# Limited IF-Statements in AppleScript?

Tags: if-statement, applescript, limit

I have been developing an AppleScript for several months now and reached around 6,000 lines of code.

It’s function is to run with Automator which receives the contents from the clipboard which are copied lines from a spreadsheet. Then, it writes these contents to various global variables.

The global variables are modified throughout and extensive logic tree in the main function and finally written back to the clipboard with an output function:

```
global SomeGlobalVariables

on OutputFunction()
    
    #write global variables to clipboard
    
end OutputFunction

on InputFunction(input, parameters)
    
    #write clipboard to global variables
    
end InputFunction

#main function

on run {input, parameters}
    
    InputFunction(input, parameters)
    
    if globalVariable1 = "Test" then

        #Code with many IF-Statements modifying global variables

    else if globalVariable1 = "Test2" then

        #Code with many IF-Statements modifying global variables
        #if globalVariable1 = "abc" then beep


    #... 
    #Code with many IF-Statements modifying global variables
    #... 
    #... 


    end if
    
end run
```

Now, I have run into a very peculiar problem:

Once I get beyond a certain amount of IF-Statements in the main function the code throws an error before I reach end run.

For example, if globalVariable1 is „Test“ the code works just fine at first.
But when I later on modify the section for „Test2“ by adding some random IF-Statements like

```
if globalVariable1 = "abc" then beep
```

I get an error message before end run. This is even though the „Test2“-section will never be processed because globalVariable1 stays „Test“ all the time.

The error messages I receive are rather random varying wildly depending on how many random IF-Statements I put to the code. Mostly they state that something cannot be converted to number/text/…

I have never heard such a thing before but is there a limit on IF-Statement I can have in my code or an obvious flaw that would explain the behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a limit, but if most of your code is grouped in the run handler, that is going to make it very difficult to troubleshoot.  You might try breaking up your script into smaller manageable handlers (for the individual globals, perhaps), then you could edit your question with a minimal script that just includes the part that has the problem.

Comment: It's too long for posting but I created an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvd5978hungcufz/Code.txt?dl=0

Once enough IF-Beep-statements are commented out it'll work again.

Comment: There are various memory and symbol table limitations, but I stand corrected - although I don't think I've ever seen a 2300 line `if` statement before.  Using lists (arrays) and records (dictionaries/hashes) would seem to be way easier to manage, but you definitely need to break things up into handlers.  For example, your dropbox script can be fixed by moving the six hundred (!) or so `if` statements for `variable2 = 6` into a handler, but this approach has a pretty strong code smell.

Comment: Thank you! Taking the statement to a handler worked for the original code, too! So you are suggesting to take the contents of the else ifs to various handlers and the just call the respective handler from the main handler? I havn't worked with lists and records yet but it sounds like it wouldn't look much leaner, too.

Comment: The main reason is to group your code into sections that perform a single task.  That makes it easier to modify and troubleshoot, and by giving your handlers and variables appropriate names, your code can also be self commenting.  Depending on what the actual code is, you might be able to use the value or whatever you are comparing as a record/dictionary key to look up a handler to perform, avoiding all those if statements.